# Image border issue on Desktop

Tags: css, media-queries

This code is working fine on Mobile Devices and giving Fixed Width and height for Images border on Mobile screen, But on Desktop its not Fixed

Screenshot here:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/klQY4.jpg

Here is js fiddle :- http://goo .gl/krRYR8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well why not apply a width on desktop too.

```
.go-home-stores .gocol-4 {
    padding: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    max-width: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark that my answer solved your problem :)